# How to bootstrap modules in Angular 2+ with server side response

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, single-page-application

I used to bootstap my Angular JS app with a call to the server to get the modules a user has access, I can't figure how in Angular 2+

This is a AngularJS exemple

I used ngMockE2E only for the mock exemple.

```js
 (function (ngNode) {
        angular.module("boostrapApp", ['ngMockE2E']).service('clientModule', function ($http) {
            this.get = function () {
                return $http.get('modules.json');
            }
        }).run(function ($httpBackend) {
            $httpBackend.whenGET('modules.json').respond(function(method, url, data) {

                return [200, ['m1', 'm2', 'm3'], {}];
            });
        });

        angular.bootstrap(ngNode, ['boostrapApp']);

        angular.element(ngNode).injector().get('clientModule').get().then(function (modules) {
            angular.module('app', modules.data);

            angular.module('app').run(['$log', function ($log) {
                $log.info('run app');
            }]);
            angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
        });
    })(document.createElement('div'));






    angular.module('m1', []).run(['$log', function ($log) {
        $log.info('run m1');
    }]);

    angular.module('m2', []).run(['$log', function ($log) {
        $log.info('run m2');
    }]);

    angular.module('m3', []).run(['$log', function ($log) {
        $log.info('run m3');
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-mocks/1.6.9/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Dynamic Content Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

Comment: nice but in Angular JS it was less complexe!